# Why does it start counting the elements in this list from list[-1] instead of list[0]? (Python 3)

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, indexing

(It's easier to explain if I show the code first)

```
import random
inventory = 100
while True:
    print('inventory: $' + str(inventory))
    print('how much do you wager?')
    wager = input()
    keys = ['a', 'b']
    cA = random.sample(keys, 1)
    print('pick "a" or "b"')
    guess = input()
    if guess == cA[0]
        inventory += int(wager)
    elif guess == cA[1]: # <--------------- 
        inventory -= int(wager)
    else:
        print('ERROR')
```

So I've made this fairly simple guessing/gambling game, but when I ran it said that cA[1] was out of range ("IndexError: list index out of range"), which confused me because as far as I know lists are supposed to start counting from list[0], list[1] etc.
I then changed cA[1] to cA[-1] and that did return a letter.  Oddly (I think) when I added on

```
print(keys[1])
```

it did return "b" as expected, so I don't understand why keys[1] exists but cA[1] doesn't when keys and cA both have 2 elements.  Why does it do this and is there a way to fix/change it?

Comment: It doesn't, I've realized that that's my problem oops

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your list has only **one** element in it:

```
cA = random.sample(keys, 1)
```

You asked for a random sample of length 1.

`-1` works because that is an index relative to the end. With a list of length 1, `listobj[-1]` is the same object as `listobj[0]`; the last element is also the first element.

`keys` is a list with *two* elements, so `keys[0]` and `keys[1]` both exist.

Comment: Also, the negative index is a Python convention for counting backward from the end of a list.  Given `a = [1,2,3]`, `a[-1]` is 3.  In your case, your list only has one item, so `a[-1]` is that one item: the same as `a[0]`.

Comment: No fair editing your answer to add the stuff I'm in the middle of writing a comment about, Martijn! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
inventory = 100
while True:
    print('inventory: $' + str(inventory))
    print('how much do you wager?')
    wager = input()
    keys = ['a', 'b']
    cA = random.sample(keys, 1)
    print('pick "a" or "b"')
    guess = input()
    if guess == cA      <------------ cA has the element that is the correct wager
        inventory += int(wager)     
    else:
        inventory -= int(wager)
```

I think that's what you want.

Comment: actually (as Martijn Pieters pointed out) my problem was I put cA = random.sample(keys, 1) when I should have put ...(keys, 2), but I actually used cA instead of keys because I wanted it to be random (hence the guessing) but thanks

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.  Still drinking my morning coffee :)

Comment: Your answer would be better if you did more than just throw some code up. Add an explanation for why your version of the code is better, and what you changed.